# How do the CloudKit security roles and permissions work?

Tags: security, permissions, cloudkit, security-roles

There are three default security roles in CloudKit:

- **World**
- **Authenticated**
- **Creator**

And three permissions:

- **Create**
- **Read**
- **Write**

How do these security roles and permissions work?

Here are examples of some of the questions I would hope get answered by an explanation of security roles:

- What do the three roles mean? The first two seem obvious, but the last one seems less so. E.g. does *Creator* refer to the creator of the table, or the creator of a record?
- Where would the deletion permission fall under? Write?
- Can security roles be applied to individual records? (E.g. I want a user to have access to only a subset of the records in the InstantMessages table: the ones they send, and the ones they receive. Can something of this nature be done via security roles?)
- Are permissions inherited? (E.g. Does the creator get all permissions granted from creator, authenticated, and world?)
- Are permissions purely additive? Or can I create a custom role that will remove privileges rather than add them? (E.g. in order to create a "Banned User" security role.)
- How do I set the role on a user? Can I set a default role for every user that is created? Can I change a user's role programmatically?
- How do I create new security roles? Can I create/update them programmatically?

Answer (score 10):

1) How do these security roles and permissions work?  You set them on the dashboard in the Development environment.

2) What do the three roles mean? The first two seem obvious, but the last one seems less so. E.g. does Creator refer to the creator of the table, or the creator of a record? - Creator of the record (and that means all devices that access CloudKit with the same iCloud Account)

3) Where would the deletion permission fall under? Write? YES

4) Can security roles be applied to individual records? NO

5) (E.g. I want a user to have access to only a subset of the records in the InstantMessages table: the ones they send, and the ones they receive. Can something of this nature be done via security roles?) What does 'access' mean?  A user can only read things that your app allows them to read and that they have read permission.  A user can only create or write (and delete) records that your app lets them create or modify (and delete) and that they have create or write permission - it takes both.

6) Are permissions inherited? (E.g. Does the creator get all permissions granted from creator, authenticated, and world?) Roles are subsets of the other - a creator is a subset of authenticated. authenticated is a subset of world.

7) Are permissions....programmatically? Permissions go to the broad class "creator" "authenticated" "world" so you can't set permission user-by-user (except that the user who creates a record is the only creator).

But key to all of this is to remember that it takes your apps code to grant create/read/write to a record AND the particular user must have that permission.  So you can do anything you want in code to allow anyone to do anything - provided you granted "Authenticated" the right to "write"

Comment: Do these roles only apply to the Public Database? What about Shared or Private?

Comment: These roles apply to the public database, and trivially, also apply to the private database.  Only one account has access to the private database.  Therefore that person is the "creator' and the creator has all rights.  End of story.  (Shared files - I'm uncertain.)

Comment: So if I host privileged data (like provided for people who bought In App Purchase) in cloudKit public database and only control is in the app logic, could that be exploited by some user somehow?

Comment: I believe that it would be very difficult for a user to alter a CloudKit database entry any way other than what the app's code allows them to do.